# Source file header file and other files are not displayed when I create empty C++ Project in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am very new to visual studio and I watched a couple of tutorials to understand how to use it, But I ran into a problem. Every person I watched on YT has a source file, header file, and other files when creating an empty Project but this isn't a case for me and I basically can't write anything.
when I try to add a CPP file it doesn't even show an option to add it, it only shows class and resource when I right click and press on add. Basically, I want the files to show so I can create my main program and play around with it.[image]

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to be in the "Solution Explorer" not the "Class View"

Comment: And note that if you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **First** Create an `empty project` .
- **Second** Go to solution explorer.
- **Third** Right click the `source file` option.
- **Fourth** Go to `add` and create a new item
- **Fifth** Select `.cpp file` and press add.

And Congrats your .cpp file is created. Do the same procedure to create header file and class.